# itext font color gets darker in first page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using iText 2.1.7,i'm adding header and footer at absolute position using writer.getDirectcontent() method.All is working fine except the fonts in first page gets darker than second pages.

Note the Header and Footer in First and second pages

[image]

[image]

anyhelp?

Here is what i did

```
Reader stringReader = new StringReader(svgXmlDoc);

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());

    ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, content);

        document.open();

        PdfService event = new PdfService();
        event.setHeader(date.toString());

        event.onOpenDocument(writer, document);
        event.onEndPage(writer, document);
        event.onCloseDocument(writer, document);
        writer.setPageEvent(event);

        Image image1 = Image.getInstance("Infinity-Loop.png");

        image1.scalePercent(35);

        PdfPTable signature = new PdfPTable(numberOfSignature);

        signature.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().getWidth()
                - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin());
        signature.setLockedWidth(true);
        signature.setWidthPercentage(100);
        signature.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);

        signature.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(
                Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSignature; i++) {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(
                    String.valueOf("____________")));
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            signature.addCell(cell);
        }

        PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(3);

        float[] columnWidths = {1f,2f,1f};
         header.setWidths(columnWidths);
        header.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().getWidth()
                - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin());
        header.setLockedWidth(true);
        header.setWidthPercentage(100);
         header.getDefaultCell().setPadding(15);
        header.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

        PdfPCell logocell = new PdfPCell(image1, false);
        logocell.setRowspan(3);
        logocell.setFixedHeight(72);
        logocell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        header.addCell(logocell);

        PdfPCell Title = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(title,
                FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
                        Font.PLAIN, new Color(0, 0, 0))));
        Title.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        Title.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        header.addCell(Title);
        header.addCell("");
        header.completeRow();
        PdfPCell SubTitle = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(subTitle));
        SubTitle.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        SubTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        header.addCell(SubTitle);
        header.addCell("");
        header.completeRow();
        PdfPCell dataRange = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                dateRange));
        dataRange.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        dataRange.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        header.addCell(dataRange);
        header.addCell("");
        header.completeRow();
        ArrayList tmp = header.getRows(0, header.getRows().size());
        header.getRows().clear();
        header.getRows().addAll(tmp);

        int width = (int) ((int) document.getPageSize().getWidth()
                - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin());
        int height = 350;
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
        Graphics2D g2 = template.createGraphics(width, height);

        PrintTranscoder prm = new PrintTranscoder();
        TranscoderInput ti = new TranscoderInput(stringReader);
        prm.transcode(ti, null);

        PageFormat pg = new PageFormat();
        Paper pp = new Paper();
        pp.setSize(width, height);
        pp.setImageableArea(0, 0, width, height);
        pg.setPaper(pp);
        prm.print(g2, pg, 0);
        g2.dispose();

        ImgTemplate img = new ImgTemplate(template);
        img.setAbsolutePosition(document.left(), document.topMargin() + 100);
        document.add(img);
        signature.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(),
                document.bottom() + document.bottomMargin() * 2,
                writer.getDirectContent());

        header.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(), document.top(),
                writer.getDirectContent());
        document.newPage();

    PdfPTable statisticsTitle=new PdfPTable(1);
    statisticsTitle.setTotalWidth(document.right() - document.left());
    statisticsTitle.setWidthPercentage(100);
    PdfPCell titleCell= new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Statistics Report"));
    titleCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    titleCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    statisticsTitle.addCell(titleCell);
    statisticsTitle.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(), document.top()
            - document.topMargin() * 2 - 10, writer.getDirectContent());

        PdfPTable table;
        if(measurementType.equals("Temp")){
            table = new PdfPTable(6);
        }
        else{
            table = new PdfPTable(11);
        }
        table.setTotalWidth(document.right() - document.left());
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setHeaderRows(1);


        PdfPCell h1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Description"));
        h1.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        h1.setRowspan(2);
        h1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
        h1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(h1);

        PdfPCell h2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Temperature"));
        h2.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        h2.setColspan(5);
        h2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(h2);

        if(measurementType.equals("TempHumi")){
            PdfPCell h3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Humidity"));
            h3.setGrayFill(0.7f);
            h3.setColspan(5);
            h3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.addCell(h3);
        }
        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        PdfPCell tc1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Min"));
        tc1.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        tc1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(tc1);

        PdfPCell tc2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Max"));
        tc2.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        tc2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(tc2);

        PdfPCell tc3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Avg"));
        tc3.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        tc3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(tc3);

        PdfPCell tc4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Std"));
        tc4.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        tc4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(tc4);

        PdfPCell tc5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Mkt"));
        tc5.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        tc5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(tc5);

        if(measurementType.equals("TempHumi")){
        PdfPCell hc1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Min"));
        hc1.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        hc1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(hc1);

        PdfPCell hc2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Max"));
        hc2.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        hc2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(hc2);

        PdfPCell hc3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Avg"));
        hc3.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        hc3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(hc3);

        PdfPCell hc4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Std"));
        hc4.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        hc4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(hc4);

        PdfPCell hc5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Mkt"));
        hc5.setGrayFill(0.7f);
        hc5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(hc5);
        }



        ArrayList tmpTable = table.getRows(0, table.getRows().size());
        table.getRows().clear();
        table.getRows().addAll(tmpTable);

        JsonObject listloggerdatastatistics = ReportService
                .getStatisticsDetails(serialnumberlist);

        System.out.println("Json "+listloggerdatastatistics.get("Sensormodellist"));

        for (int row = 0; row < listloggerdatastatistics.get("Sensormodellist").getAsJsonArray().size(); row++) {
            JsonObject jsonobj=listloggerdatastatistics.get("Sensormodellist").getAsJsonArray().get(row).getAsJsonObject();
            if (row > 20 && row % 21 == 0) {

                table.completeRow();

                table.writeSelectedRows(0, 22, document.left(),
                        document.top() - document.topMargin() * 2 - 10,
                        writer.getDirectContent());
                table.deleteBodyRows();
                table.setSkipFirstHeader(true);
                signature.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(),
                        document.bottom() + document.bottomMargin() * 3,
                        writer.getDirectContent());

                header.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(),
                        document.top(), writer.getDirectContent());

                document.newPage();
            }



            table.addCell(jsonobj.get("Modeltype").getAsString());
            table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Mintemperature").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Maxtemperature").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Avgtemperature").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Stdtemperature").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Mkttemperature").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            if(measurementType.equals("TempHumi")){
                table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Minhumidity").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
                table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Maxhumidity").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
                table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Avghumidity").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
                table.addCell(""+jsonobj.get("Stdhumidity").getAsBigDecimal().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
                table.addCell("-");
            }


        }

        table.completeRow();
        table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(), document.top()
                - document.topMargin() * 3 - 10, writer.getDirectContent());
        signature.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(),
                document.bottom() + document.bottomMargin() * 2,
                writer.getDirectContent());
        header.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(), document.top(),
                writer.getDirectContent());


    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    document.close();
    content.close();
```

I'm constructing graph image from SVG and table data are populated from database

Event handlers for adding footer with page X of Y

```
public class PdfService extends PdfPageEventHelper {
/** The header text. */
String header;
/** The template with the total number of pages. */
PdfTemplate total;

/**
 * Fills out the total number of pages before the document is closed.
 * 
 * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onCloseDocument(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,
 *      com.itextpdf.text.Document)
 */
@Override
public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    total.reset();
    ColumnText
            .showTextAligned(total, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                    new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber() - 1)),
                    2, 2, 0);

}

/**
 * Adds a header to every page
 * 
 * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,
 *      com.itextpdf.text.Document)
 */
@Override
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
    try {
        table.setWidths(new float[] { (float) (2.25), (float) (1.5), 11, 13 });
        table.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().getWidth()
                - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin());
        table.setLockedWidth(true);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
        table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        table.addCell(String.format("Page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()));
        Image img = Image.getInstance(total);
        Chunk conte = new Chunk(img, 0, 0);
        Phrase chunk = new Phrase(conte);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(chunk);
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);

        table.addCell(cell);
        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        table.addCell("SuperAdmin");
        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        table.addCell(header);
        table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.leftMargin(),
                document.bottom(), writer.getDirectContent());

    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the PdfTemplate that will hold the total number of pages.
 * 
 * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onOpenDocument(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,
 *      com.itextpdf.text.Document)
 */
@Override
public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    total = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(15, 14);
    // total.setBoundingBox(new Rectangle(-1, 6, 20, 20));
}

/**
 * Allows us to change the content of the header.
 * 
 * @param header
 *            The new header String
 */
public void setHeader(String header) {
    this.header = header;
}
}
```

Comment: They aren't _darker_... they're **bolder**.

Comment: okay..thanks for the correction..anyway i've not set anything to make them bold

Comment: Well... then _What Exactly Have You Done_?

Comment: updated question for your reference..thanks

Comment: Hmm... It'll take some time deciphering the code... Are the two documents of the same _size_ (`Dimension`)?

Comment: that is not two documents..it's two pages of same document..also i'm a beginner to itext and java..better implementations are there..if you suggest something that ill be very helpful for me...

Comment: Well... that's the same problem for me! ;-) I don't even know what `itext` is... I'm guessing. (Don't worry... if ur question doesn't get enough reputation, I'll offer a bounty for it.)

Comment: You might consider using an up-to-date version of iText. 2.1.7 is almost 5 years old...

Comment: @AlexisPigeon, due to itext developers moved to AGPL license,sticking with itext2.1.7 itself.

Comment: Read http://lowagie.com/heartbleed_asl_bumodel and you'll understand why the AGPL is the better license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In old days, when people had one font program for one regular font and no separate font file for a bold font, people found ways to work around this problem, and Adobe Reader was adapted to make this workaround work.

The workaround consists of writing the same content twice (or more) at the same position. When you add "Page 1 of 2" once, the font is presented as a regular font. When you add it twice, the font is presented as a bold font.

This is what happens in your case: you are adding the footer twice. This is wrong:

```
document.open();
PdfService event = new PdfService();
event.setHeader(date.toString());
event.onOpenDocument(writer, document);
event.onEndPage(writer, document);
event.onCloseDocument(writer, document);
writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

You invoke `event.onEndPage()` yourself, adding the footer a first time. When a page is finished, iText calls the `onEndPage()` method a second time, adding the footer once more, resulting in a bold font.

You should adapt your code like this:

```
PdfService event = new PdfService();
event.setHeader(date.toString());
writer.setPageEvent(event);
document.open();
```

You should declare the event to the `PdfWriter` instance *before* opening the document. You should not call the `onOpenDocument()`, `onEndPage()` and `onCloseDocument()` methods yourself! They are called internally by iText.

You should also upgrade to the latest version for the reasons explained on the [FAQ](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq). [Using Open Source and contributing nothing in return is unwise. Supporting your open source communities isn’t charity, it’s good business.](http://lowagie.com/heartbleed_asl_bumodel)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.I Understood the efforts behind developers like you.forwarded your article to my colleague too..right now doing a RND..ill move to latest version soon..i've read your book iText in action..Awesome!

Comment: i got that footer fixed but header still darker than second page..tried by removing document.newPage() but content gets overlaped in the same page..

Comment: Can you share the PDF? That way, we can examine if the text is still being added twice. Difference in color can also be caused by the blending mode. Black on Black&White pages can be different than black on colored pages because in the former DeviceGray is used as color space whereas DeviceCMYK can be used in the latter. In that case, using `writer.setRgbTransparencyBlending()` can do the trick. (It's a problem that has been discussed in the ISO committee for PDF many times.)

Comment: here is the pdf https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3IRPs7dec7zX1pBOVRCa3ZrdVk/edit?usp=sharing .Using PNG images in pdf creates any problem?

Comment: I've opened the PDF in Adobe Reader and I've put the two pages next to each other (see screen shot added to my answer). I don't see any difference. Can you explain the nature of the problem? Where do I have to look to see a difference?

Comment: Furthermore, when looking at your PDF, I see that you didn't try `writer.setRgbTransparencyBlending(true);`

Comment: Thank you so much..actually the PDF is created as a ByteArrayOutputStream then streamed to the browser directly..this issue happens only when viewing PDF directly in the browser..yes when opened in Adobe Reader cant see any difference between headers..